# PowerShell v2.0+ add a computer to a domain global group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I'm using `PowerShell` version 2.0 and wanted to know how to add a Domain Computer into a Domain Global Group.

Also I would like to know if there is a good site to go to that has `V2` commands and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late but, you can use `PowerShell`'s `Active Directory` modulde to do this in `PowerShell 2.0`:

```
Import-Module activedirectory

$globalGroup = "Your_Global_Group"
$computerName = "Your Computer Name"

$computerObj = Get-ADComputer $computerName -properties *
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $globalGroup -Members $computerObj.DistinguishedName
```

**Note**: You will need to turn on the `Active Directory` windows feature to be able to use the `activedirectory` module. This can be found under 'Remote Sever Administration tools' tab in windows features.

Link: [For Cmdlet's in the AD module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx)